# Delete contact list on samsung nexus cellphone

Tags: delete

I want to delete my entire contact list from my samsung nexus, is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable Contact Sync from Settings → Accounts, and then go into Applications and find Contacts and Contacts Storage and hit Clear Data under both of them.